# Schedule a python code to run for some hours a day in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a python app in Heroku server from 8:30 am to 4 pm everyday from Monday to Friday. Close the app after 4 pm and then restart it next day.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem? Is it related to working out the time, or only making the app work at those times?

Comment: I want to make app work on those times only to minimise the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [flask-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/flask-crontab/) or [Flask APScheduler](https://viniciuschiele.github.io/flask-apscheduler/index.html).